# Сниффер на с++ и Winsock2

Tags: c++, winsock

Я стараюсь создать собственный снифер, вот что я уже сделал. Единственная беда никак не могу выполнить байнд, может подскажете в чем беда. WSAGetLastError = 10038

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
void main()
{

    struct sockaddr saddr;
    int sa_size,data_size;
    char Buffer[1024];
    WSADATA wsaData;
    struct sockaddr_in sa;

    int Result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (Result != 0){
        cout << "WSA strtup failed " << Result << endl;
    }

    char hostname[100];
    int in = 0;
    WSADATA wsa;
    if (gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        cout << "Unable to get hostname" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    struct hostent *local = gethostbyname(hostname);
    if (local == NULL){
        cout << "Got an error " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    SOCKET raw_sock;
    cout << "Host name: " << hostname << endl;
    raw_sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (raw_sock<0){
        cout << "Unable to create raw socket: " << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    in_addr addr;
    cout << "RAW socket has been created" << endl;
    cout << "Available Network Interfaces" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; local->h_addr_list[i] != 0; ++i){
        memcpy(&addr, local->h_addr_list[i], sizeof(struct in_addr));
        cout << "Interface [ " << i << " ]: Adress " << inet_ntoa(addr) << endl;
    }

    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    memcpy(&sa.sin_addr.s_addr, local->h_addr_list[in], sizeof(sa.sin_addr.s_addr));
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port = 0;
    if (bind(raw_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&sa, sizeof(sa)) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        cout << "Error binding" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(raw_sock);
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "Bind completed" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Основная беда в том, что это не сниффер.

Comment: @kff В будущем он им станет

Comment: Результат WSAGetLastError, конечно же, публиковать не надо. Пускай все догадаются?

Comment: Я уже догадался - 10038. Socket operation on nonsocket.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Начнём с того, что проверка на правильность создания сокета проводится неправильно. Надо так:

```
if (raw_sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
   // Обработка ошибки.
}
```

Чтобы создался RAW-сокет, программу нужно запускать с правами администратора. Тогда получаем ошибку `WSAEINVAL` (10022, Invalid argument). Она связана с неверными параметрами при создании сокета. Исправляем:

```
raw_sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);
```

Теперь `bind` проходит успешно.